# How can I restart a function if the argument isn't numeric?

Tags: python

I'm writing a GPA calculator, and I want to ensure the number of classes inputted is a numeric value. How can I make the function below loop back if it's not?

```
def get_num_classes(n):
    num_classes = n
    if n.isnumeric():
        return int(num_classes)
    else:
        #???
```

In the main file, the function is called as:
`num_classes = grade_fcns.get_num_classes(input("Number of classes this semester: "))`

Comment: Can you clarify as to what do you mean by loopback here?

Comment: as in re-prompt the user for input and re-run the function to check if the input is numeric and return it if it is.

Comment: just put `get_num_classes(input("Number of classes this semester: "))` in the `else` part of the  code

Comment: @pdrersin I tried that, but it didn't seem to be executing the subsequent return element properly.

Comment: @JohnAllison I was missing a return statement there. It is fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `while` loop to delegate the verification of the input to `int`:

```
def get_num_classes():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input("Number of classes this semester: "))
        except ValueError:
            print('Try again')

print(get_num_classes())
```

Example:

```
Number of classes this semester: s
Try again
Number of classes this semester: sd
Try again
Number of classes this semester: 3
3
```

The solution is not prone to an infinite recursion (and the inevitable stack overflow).

Comment: @VasuDeo.S The entire premise of OP's question is having the function, which I presume has some other logic than only what we were shown in the question

Comment: I like your solution. But c'mon it is a simple function call. All you need would be one or two more calls, that is it.

Comment: @pdrersin Please execute your code, and provide an invalid answer for 996 times.

Comment: @DeepSpace and why would I do that?

Comment: @pdrersin Because that's what breaks it

Comment: @VasuDeo.S I do call the function later on a few different times ~ it's a small project, and I plan on implementing it to be used both for a single semester and cumulative hence the need for functions.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `None` does not make sense (I mean, this has no other sense as "Not a valid stuff"), I would try this:

```
def get_num_classes(n):
    num_classes = n
    if n.isnumeric():
        return int(num_classes)
    return None #There's no need of else here, once we're talking about return statements
```

and then call it from a `while(True)` statement:

```
while (True):
    answer = get_num_classes(input("Number of classes this semester: "))
    if answer is not None:
        #Do something else
        break
    else:
        print("Try again...\n")
```

This approach is not recursive, but you should be careful about the `while(True)`, once it can hang there forever. You could even use a try/except approach, where you can, for instance, check for other criteria: is it an integer? Is it greater than 0? Is is between `x` and `y`? And, if these criteria are not met, raise an exception, like `AttributeError` and then catch it in the main code.

Hope it helps